# I am attempting a hash map that stores vector of objects. in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I am attempting a hash map that stores vector of objects.

Explanation / Goal in words. 
if no key is not found, create an new entry.
if a key is found, push a new object into vector of objects

In pseudo code I am attempting

```
map<string,vector<Object>>    
data object{
    int data
    vector<keywords> keywords
}    
function(object arg)
{
    local_key_var = object->keywords;    
    for ( key_element : local_key_var)
    {
        if(key_element does not exist in vector<Object> )
        {
            create entry as  map<key_element,vector<Object>    
        } 
        else 
        {
            local_vector_var = current vectorObject;    
            local_vetor_var.push(arg);    
            erase current vector object;    
            insert new_vector_var int map<key_element,vector<objects>>;
        }    
    }    
}
```

In c++ code this is where I am at.

```
void Library::addItemByKeyWord(Item*  item)
{    

    vector<string> localKeyVector = item->getKeywords();    

    for (auto element : localKeyVector) // access by reference to avoid copying
    {    

        map<string, vector<Item**>>::const_iterator it = keywordLib.find(element);
        if(it == keywordLib.end()) // not found
        {    

            vector<Item**> localVector;
            localVector.push_back(&item);
            keywordLib.insert(pair<string,vector<Item**>>(item->getTitle(),localVector));    

        }
        else // found
        {
            // copy found stack of items to vector
            vector<Item**> localVector = it->second;    

            // push passed in item on top of new copy
            localVector.push_back(&item);    

            // remove old map entry //
            keywordLib.erase(it);    

            // push new copy of vectors on top of hash //
            keywordLib.insert(pair<string,vector<Item**>>(item->getTitle(),localVector));
        }
    }
```

Please note the below code may not be my best attempt yet. I have been stuck on this for longer than I care to admit and I think it is time as someone.

Comment: `&item` takes the address of the stack. It will be invalid when the function returns.

Comment: You can't just do `keywordLib[element].push_back(<whatever>);` ?

Comment: let me try, i will let you know.

Comment: @JonathanPotter That appears to work thank you!

Comment: @Dani thank you, I had to follow your suggestion as well.